# How to use itemsIndexed properly

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using a function to display data in a table. For each index in a list, the function below interrogates the index and displays each item in the class.

What if I only want to see the first 3 items in the list?
e.g. List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
I only want the function below to run through 4 & 5

```
@Composable
fun FirstTable(dataList: List<AircraftData>)
{

 itemsIndexed(dataList) { _, data ->
        Row(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            val color = if(data.item=="R Seat") Color.Red else Color.White

            TableCell(
                text = data.item,
                alignment = TextAlign.Center,
                color = color
            )
            TableCell(text = data.weight)
            TableCell(text = data.armx)
            TableCell(text = data.army)
            TableCell(text = data.momx)
            TableCell(text = data.momy)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow what you want.  You say:

> I only want to see the first 3 items in the list

in a list with 1,2,3,4,5

and then you say

> I only want the function below to run through 4 & 5

so this seems the inverse of what you want.

Also, I don't know what the method `itemsIndexed(..) {..}` does, but even still, I think the solution you need is simple:

1. if you want the first 3 elements

```
fun FirstTable(dataList: List<AircraftData>)
{
 require(dataList.size>=3) // if it is not, you'll need to adjust the indices
 itemsIndexed(dataList.subList(0,3)) { _, data ->
        Row(
```

2. if you **don't** want the first 3 elements

```
fun FirstTable(dataList: List<AircraftData>)
{
 require(dataList.size>3) // if it is not, you'll need to adjust the indices
 itemsIndexed(dataList.subList(3, dataList.size)) { _, data ->
        Row(
```

Comment: apologies for the mistaken nonsense - too many hours at the keyboard.